# istream function parameter vs inline std::cin

Tags: c++, input, stream

How these two function differs? Is there any different kinds of istream other than std::cin and what is the point of returning the istream?

```
using namespace std; 

istream& readInput(istream& in, vector<string>& wordList)
{
    string word;
    while (in >> word)
    {
        wordList.push_back(word);
    } 

    in.clear();

    return in;
}

void readInput(vector<string>& wordList)
{
    string word;
    while (cin >> word)
    {
        wordList.push_back(word);
    } 

    cin.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `cin` is absolutely not the only one `istream`, I think that it is not even the most used one. Read about e.g. `ifstream` and `istringstream`.
2. Returning `istream&` from the function may be useful in various situations - it depends on the context. For just simple calls of `readInput` one can skip it and make the function `void`.